# Banned and kicked logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a ban and kick script and it's working, but when a user gets a ban, the bot sends a ban and a kick message (even if the user gets a ban). I want it to send only the ban message when the user receives the ban, and the kick message only when the user receives a kick.

```
client.on(Events.GuildBanRemove, async (ban) => {
    const fetchedLogs = await ban.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: AuditLogEvent.MemberBanRemove,
    });
    const unbanLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
    const { executor, target } = unbanLog;

    if (target.id === ban.user.id) {
        const channel2 = client.channels.cache.get("1026979529387950132");
        const embed2 = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("#10fee4")
            .setThumbnail(`${client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048 })}`)
            .setTitle(`Log | Usuario Desbanido.`)
            .setDescription(`**Informações do usuario:**\n > Membro:${ban.user}\n > ID:\`${ban.user.id}\`\n\n**Informações do unban**:\n > Desbanido por: ${executor}\n> ID:\`${executor.id}\``)
            .setFooter({ text: `© ${client.user.username} 2023` })
            .setTimestamp(new Date());
        channel2.send({ embeds: [embed2] });
    }
});

client.on(Events.GuildMemberRemove, async (member) => {
    const fetchedLogs2 = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: AuditLogEvent.MemberKick,
    });
    const kickLog = fetchedLogs2.entries.first();
    const { executor, target } = kickLog;

    if (target.id === member.id) {
        const channel3 = client.channels.cache.get("1026979529387950132");
        const embed3 = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("#10fee4")
            .setThumbnail(`${client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048 })}`)
            .setTitle(`Log | Usuario Expulso.`)
            .setDescription(`**Informações do usuario:**\n > Membro:${member.user}\n > ID:\`${member.user.id}\`\n\n**Informações da expulsão:**\n > Expulso por: ${executor}\n> ID:\`${executor.id}\``)
            .setFooter({ text: `© ${client.user.username} 2023` })
            .setTimestamp(new Date());
        channel3.send({ embeds: [embed3] });
    }
});
```